# JComboBox actionListener doesn't function

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have a class that has 4 private attributes, and through a JComboBox selection, I want to modify them through calling a procedure. However, it seems like even though the JComboBox appears with the selection, the attributes that are shown don't change.

```
public class PanneauVehicule extends JPanel {


private String[] vehicules;
private int majCarburant;
private int majPassager;


public class PanneauVehicule extends JPanel {
//Main constructor
   public PanneauVehicule(){
       //Creates a JPanel
       super();
       //Sets layout as BorderLayout
       setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       initListeVehicule();
       initLabels();
    }
 public void initListeVehicule(){

    vehicules = new String[] {Constantes.CS100 , Constantes.CS300 , 
            Constantes.GREYHOUND102D3 , Constantes.GREYHOUNDG4500 , 
            Constantes.TGVATLANTIQUE , Constantes.TGVDUPLEX};

    final JComboBox<String> vehiculesList = new JComboBox<>(vehicules);
    //Keep in mind the comboBox does appear with the right selections
    add(vehiculesList,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //Here's where it doesnt work.
    vehiculesList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            majInfo(2,4);
        }
    });
}
public void majInfo(int test1, int test2){
    this.majCarburant = test2;
    this.majPassager = test1;
}

public void initLabels(){

    JPanel panneauBas = new JPanel();
    panneauBas.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,5,5));

    JLabel labelCarburant = new JLabel();
    labelCarburant.setText("Type de caburant: " + this.majCarburant);

    JLabel labelPassagers = new JLabel();
    labelPassagers.setText("Nb de passagers: " + this.majPassager);

    panneauBas.add(labelPassagers);
    panneauBas.add(labelCarburant);

    add(panneauBas, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panneauBas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

After that, I use another procedure that will make majCarburant and majPassager appear on screen. However their values are shown as default (0). I can make their values change manually without using an ActionListener, but the task at hand requires me to use one.

Comment: All your code does is update the value of the majCarburant and majPassager variables. Variables don't display on the screen. You need to update the Swing component with the new value. Since it appears you are using JLabels on your GUI, you would need to use the `setText(...)` method to change the display of the label. If you need more help and in the future when you ask a question post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I mentionned that I used a function that does display on screen the values through JLabels and setText. I figured it wasn't necessary that I add that, but it is basically the initLabels(); called in the beginning. I can't  fit it in because of character limit.

Comment: `initLables()` is used when you create the GUI. It has nothing to do when you want to change the value displayed in the label. **You need to invoke the setText() method on the label to change its value!!!**. Changing the value of a variable does nothing.

Comment: `I can't fit it in because of character limit`  - that is because you have not posted an `MCVE`. Your question is about changing the value of a label when an ActionEvent is generated. So create a JFrame with a label and a JButton with an ActionListener. When the button is clicked, change the text. Get that working first, then apply the knowledge to your real application.

Comment: I do invoke setText in the `initLabels()`. I also invoke this procedure AFTER calling `initListeVehicule()`.

Comment: `I can make their values change manually without using an ActionListener, but the task at hand requires me to use one.` - Your ActionListener calls majInfo(...). That is is where you need the logic to dynamically change the labels text!!!

Comment: You need to / should update the new value into JLabel while every changing is made.

Comment: in `majInfo()`, i'm only updating the local-class variables majCarburant and majPassager. In initLabels, I'm essentially creating labels and setting their text to `label1.setText("......." + this.majCarburant` and adding the whole panel containing the labels into the main panel **after** invoking `initVehiculeListe` which implements the actionListener.

Comment: Do you even know what an ActionListener is? The ActionListener is invoked  AFTER the frame is visible and the user makes a selection of an item from the combo box. When you create the labels, the values of your variables are 0, so the text in the label is 0. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for working examples that show how to use an ActionListener with a combo box to do dynamic processing.

Comment: I've been trying ways to just simply change the values through actionListener directly, it just seems that the code never ''runs'' into the actionListener on ComboBox selection.

Comment: (1-) `It seems that the code never ''runs'' into the actionListener on ComboBox selection.` - of course it does. You have been given a link to the tutorial showing how it works. If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] with just a frame and a combo box and an ActionLIstener that simply displays a method when you select an item from the combo box. I don't have any more time to spend, because you don't appear to understand the basics of using a combo box or an ActionListener. That is what the tutorial are for. Read them.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying ways to just simply change the values through actionListener directly,

You don't invoke an ActionListener directly. Once an ActionListener has been added to the combo box, you can invoke:

1. `setSelectedItem(...)` or
2. `setSelectedIndex(...)`

on the combo box and the combo box will invoke the `ActionListener`.

Comment: What does setSelectedItem or Index have to do with this? Please don't downtalk to me, I've had multiple instances where I would work with JComboBox and actionListener, however this is the first i'm attempting to do dynamic processing. I have read tutorials and watched videos for the past 2 days and still can't get it work. You keep misinterpretating what I say -- read carefully.

Comment: `You keep misinterpretating what I say -- read carefully.` - I have answered thousands of questions and generally understand what people are asking. If my suggestions don't help it is because 1) your question isn't clear or 2) you don't understand my suggestions. Again, that is the reason for posting a proper [mcve]. It forces YOU to simplify the problem so everybody can see exactly what you are doing and execute the code to clarify what is happening.

Comment: `What does setSelectedItem or Index have to do with this?` - I am making a guess at what you are really asking, because you posted code indicates you don't really know what you are doing. `this is the first i'm attempting to do dynamic processing.` - and you appear NOT to understand what dynamic processing is. Again the way to clear up these misunderstandings is with a proper question and a proper `MCVE` demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after a few more hours of meddling. I just integrated the procedure that creates labels into initListeVehicule, and from there the ActionListener can access the labels to modify their texts.

```
public void initListeVehiculeInfos(){

    vehicules = new String[] {Constantes.CS100 , Constantes.CS300 , 
            Constantes.GREYHOUND102D3 , Constantes.GREYHOUNDG4500 , 
            Constantes.TGVATLANTIQUE , Constantes.TGVDUPLEX};

    final JComboBox<String> vehiculesList = new JComboBox<>(vehicules);
    add(vehiculesList,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel panneauBas = panelGenerator();
    //these setTexts serve as default values before doing your first selection

    final JLabel carb = labelGenerator();
    carb.setText("Carburant: Kérosène");

    final JLabel passager = labelGenerator();
    passager.setText("Nb Passager: 110");


    vehiculesList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            InterfaceVehicules info = FabriqueVehicule.obtenirVehicule(vehiculesList.getSelectedIndex());
            carb.setText("Carburant: " + info.tabNomTypeCarburant[info.getTypeCarburant()] );
            passager.setText("Nb Passagers: " + info.getNbPassagersMax());
        }
    });

    panneauBas.add(carb);
    panneauBas.add(passager);

    add(panneauBas, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}
```

Comment: The labels and combo box should be defined as instance variables. Then they can be accessed by any method in your class.